# JSF SelectOneMenu Tag

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss7.x, selectonemenu

I am getting an error while trying to choose item from drop down list in jsf

```
<h:form id="form">

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{currenccyRatesModel.mainCurrency}" converter="currencyDto"
        valueChangeListener="#{currencyRatesController.loadCurrencyRates}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{currenccyRatesModel.bankCurrencies}"
            var="selectedCurrency" itemValue="#{selectedCurrency}"
            itemLabel="#{selectedCurrency.curLabe}" />
        <f:ajax render="currencyRatesTable" event="change" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:dataTable id="currencyRatesTable" var="currencyRate"
        value="#{currenccyRatesModel.currencyRates}">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{currencyRate.targetCurrency}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{currencyRate.ccrRate}" />
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>


</h:form>
```

the error thrown in the web browser is **cannot convert currency@323536 java.lang.String to type ....CurrencyDto**

is there somting wrong with this, I used the same thing in a previous project and is worked fine.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

When you use java class as converter in `h:selectOneMenu`, then this class (CurrencyDto in your case) must implements `Converter` interface, in other words this class should have to contain following methods:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
```

In your case `currenccyRatesModel.mainCurrency` is not compatible with object which is expected as parameter in converter method(s).